# ajax polling: requests sent more frequently than setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, polling

I have the following ajax polling code:

```
function pollStatus(url){
    $.get(url, function(response){
        if (response.uploaded === null){
            setTimeout(pollStatus(url), 5000);
        }
    };
}
```

when i look at the network tab, i see requests being sent almost every second instead of 5 seconds as specified in settimeout. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is being invoked immediately, since you have to pass a parameter in the `timeout`, use an anonymous func:

```
 setTimeout(function() {
     pollStatus(url)
 }, 5000);
```